# Python - Methods

Tags: python, python-2.7, intellisense

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

x1App = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
```

I have created an object for excel.

Now I want to know the list of methods available for the object x1App

When I print dir(x1App). I am getting the following list

```
['_ApplyTypes_', '_FlagAsMethod', '_LazyAddAttr_', '_NewEnum', '_Release_', '__ArToID__', '__LazyMap__', '__call__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__getattr__', '__getem__', '__init__', '__int__', '__len__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__nonzero__, '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__str__', '_builtMethods_', '_enum, '_find_dispatch_type_', '_get_good_object_', '_get_good_single_object_', '_lydata_', '_make_method_', '_mapCachedItems_', '_oleobj_', '_olerepr_', '_printetails_', '_proc_', '_unicode_to_string_', '_username_', '_wrap_dispatch_']
```

but no where in the list it displays "Workbooks".

After creating the object x1App. I want to add workbook. Why it's not displaying Workbooks

Comment: At a guess, this looks like a COM component, and the COM QueryInterface method is probably being handled dynamically through `__getattr__` (which is called when you access an attribute and it isn't found); until you try to access a given name, it won't actually know if it exists, and it won't show up in a `__dir__` listing.

Comment: Yes. It's a COM component

Comment: If you are trying to manipulate Excel workbooks, I would recommend using one of the Pthon libraries, [xlwt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt) / [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd), [xlsxwriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/) or [openpyxl](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/default/usage.html) (other libraries are available). As you are discovering, documentation on the COM interface to Excel is hard to find...

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the early binding yourself. In the PythonWin GUI application goto the menu:

```
Tools --> COM MakePy Utility
```

select the Excel version you would like to work with from the long list and trigger the generation. This might a few seconds. Now you should get much better attribute suggestions.

Comment: I tried the same but  still it's not displaying "Workbooks".

Comment: I added   below two library  .                                                                                          Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library(1.6)
Microsoft Excel 5.0 Object Library(1.0)                                                                          But still it doesn't show "Workbooks"